How to render SQL Function in Hibernate 6
I am trying to migrate a project from Hibernate 5.2 to Hibernate 6 and I don't have a deep understanding of Hibernate but I'm learning step by step.
I'm stuck on updating the renderSQLFunction method. It worked fine in Hibernate 5.2 but I don't know how SQL function rendering has changed in Hibernate 6 especially with the dialect updates.
I have done some research but I haven't found a clear solution.
public String renderSQLFunction(String functionName, String param0, String param1) {
        SQLFunction function = Dialect.getDialect(MapUtils.toProperties(((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory)
                .getProperties())).getFunctions().get(functionName);
        if (function == null) {
            return functionName + "(" + param0 + "," + param1 + ")";
        }
        return function.render(IntegerType.INSTANCE,
                Lists.newArrayList(param0, param1), (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory);

Can anyone help in this please ?
